# laravel/valet: Nginx is not coming up

Tags: nginx, homebrew, laravel-valet

I recently opened an issue on GitHub, but the more I think about it, the more confident I am, this is not a valet-bug, so I guess if I can gather more information, I am going to close this issue.

### The problem

I was installing valet just like shown in the docs on my MacBook. Now I don't get a connection to :80 as NGINX is not running. As you might know, valet uses brew to install the required packages like Nginx and php.

The `install` command of valet returned:

```
➜  valet valet install 
Stopping nginx...
Installing nginx...
[nginx] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
Installing nginx configuration...
Installing nginx directory...
Updating PHP configuration...
Restarting php...
Installing dnsmasq...
[dnsmasq] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
Updating Dnsmasq configuration...
Restarting dnsmasq...
Valet is configured to serve for TLD [.test]
Restarting nginx...

Valet installed successfully!
```

But: The Nginx is not running, as shown here

```
sudo brew services list
256
Name    Status  User File
dnsmasq started root 
nginx   error   root 
php     started root
```

The syntax-check is giving no result, too:

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But the Nginx-error-log shows this:

```
2021/11/27 19:30:41 [emerg] 73996#0: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
/opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log (END)
```

Well... That's kinda non informative for me. Alright, the service got an unexpected end of parameter and crashed with an emerg, but where did that parameter even come from?

Well, for sure there are no left-overs in the process list:

```
ps aux | grep nginx   
ahoi          74430  99,6  0,1 408788096  24496 s002  R+    7:37pm   1:13.64 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox -r nginx . --exclude-dir=Entwicklung
ahoi          74553   0,0  0,0 408628336   1632 s001  S+    7:38pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox nginx
```

The `valet diagnose` returns

```
<details>
<summary>sw_vers</summary>
<pre>ProductName:   macOS
ProductVersion: 12.0.1
BuildVersion:   21A559</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>valet --version</summary>
<pre>Laravel Valet 2.16.1</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>cat ~/.config/valet/config.json</summary>
<pre>{
    "tld": "test",
    "loopback": "127.0.0.1",
    "paths": [
        "/Users/ahoi/Entwicklung/Laravel"
    ]
}</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>cat ~/.composer/composer.json</summary>
<pre>{
    "require": {
        "laravel/valet": "^2.16"
    }
}</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>composer global diagnose</summary>
<pre>Changed current directory to /Users/ahoi/.composer
Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.1.12
PHP version: 8.0.13
PHP binary path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.13_1/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
cURL version: 7.80.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1l
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>composer global outdated</summary>
<pre>Changed current directory to /Users/ahoi/.composer
Legend:
! patch or minor release available - update recommended
~ major release available - update possible
psr/container                 1.1.2  ~ 2.0.2  Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/simple-cache              1.0.1  ~ 3.0.0  Common interfaces for simple caching
symfony/deprecation-contracts v2.5.0 ~ v3.0.0 A generic function and convention to trigger deprecation notices
symfony/service-contracts     v2.5.0 ~ v3.0.0 Generic abstractions related to writing services</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al /etc/sudoers.d/</summary>
<pre>total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 18 Okt 05:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  82 root  wheel  2624 27 Nov 17:08 ..</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew config</summary>
<pre>HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.3.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 354718c40a4e7cc4e5d1d4b03fdce8b992e04e8a
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: f884b0f19efc9f7249caf5479acf8938c81cc857
Core tap last commit: 89 seconds ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 13.0.0 build 1300
Git: 2.30.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.77.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.0.1-arm64
CLT: 13.1.0.0.1.1633545042
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew services list</summary>
<pre>Name    Status  User File
dnsmasq stopped      
nginx   stopped      
php     stopped</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew list --formula --versions | grep -E "(php|nginx|dnsmasq|mariadb|mysql|mailhog|openssl)(@\d\..*)?\s"</summary>
<pre>dnsmasq 2.86
nginx 1.21.4
openssl@1.1 1.1.1l_1
php 8.0.13_1</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew outdated</summary>
<pre></pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew tap</summary>
<pre>homebrew/cask
homebrew/core
homebrew/services
shivammathur/php</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>php -v</summary>
<pre>PHP 8.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2021 11:02:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>which -a php</summary>
<pre>/opt/homebrew/bin/php</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>php --ini</summary>
<pre>Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>nginx -v</summary>
<pre>nginx version: nginx/1.21.4</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>curl --version</summary>
<pre>curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) libcurl/7.77.0 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.42.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>php --ri curl</summary>
<pre>curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.80.0
Age => 9
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => No
HTTPS_PROXY => Yes
MULTI_SSL => Yes
BROTLI => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, gophers, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => arm-apple-darwin21.1.0
SSL Version => (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1l
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.10.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
curl.cainfo => no value => no value</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>~/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/bin/ngrok version</summary>
<pre>ngrok version 2.3.40</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al ~/.ngrok2</summary>
<pre>ls: /Users/ahoi/.ngrok2: No such file or directory</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew info nginx</summary>
<pre>nginx: stable 1.21.4 (bottled), HEAD
HTTP(S) server and reverse proxy, and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
https://nginx.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx/1.21.4 (26 files, 2.2MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-11-27 at 19:30:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/nginx.rb
License: BSD-2-Clause
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@1.1, pcre
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Docroot is: /opt/homebrew/var/www

The default port has been set in /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to 8080 so that
nginx can run without sudo.

nginx will load all files in /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/servers/.

To restart nginx after an upgrade:
  brew services restart nginx
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
==> Analytics
install: 50,022 (30 days), 137,469 (90 days), 512,969 (365 days)
install-on-request: 49,922 (30 days), 137,147 (90 days), 511,686 (365 days)
build-error: 71 (30 days)</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew info php</summary>
<pre>php: stable 8.0.13 (bottled), HEAD
General-purpose scripting language
https://www.php.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.13_1 (500 files, 77.7MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-11-27 at 19:29:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/php.rb
License: PHP-3.01
==> Dependencies
Build: httpd, pkg-config
Required: apr, apr-util, argon2, aspell, autoconf, curl, freetds, gd, gettext, gmp, icu4c, krb5, libffi, libpq, libsodium, libzip, oniguruma, openldap, openssl@1.1, pcre2, sqlite, tidy-html5, unixodbc
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/

To restart php after an upgrade:
  brew services restart php
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
==> Analytics
install: 104,191 (30 days), 221,517 (90 days), 685,132 (365 days)
install-on-request: 81,207 (30 days), 196,348 (90 days), 651,204 (365 days)
build-error: 87 (30 days)</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>brew info openssl</summary>
<pre>openssl@3: stable 3.0.0 (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openssl@3.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Required: ca-certificates
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/certs

and run
  /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin/c_rehash

openssl@3 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.

==> Analytics
install: 84,630 (30 days), 192,361 (90 days), 192,362 (365 days)
install-on-request: 71,236 (30 days), 158,032 (90 days), 158,033 (365 days)
build-error: 4,430 (30 days)</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>openssl version -a</summary>
<pre>LibreSSL 2.8.3
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>openssl ciphers</summary>
<pre>ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:GOST2012256-GOST89-GOST89:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA256:CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA256:CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>sudo nginx -t</summary>
<pre>nginx: the configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>which -a php-fpm</summary>
<pre>/opt/homebrew/sbin/php-fpm</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>/opt/homebrew/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm -v</summary>
<pre>PHP 8.0.13 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Nov 24 2021 11:02:21)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>sudo /opt/homebrew/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm -y /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf --test</summary>
<pre>[27-Nov-2021 19:42:42] NOTICE: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf test is successful</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al ~/Library/LaunchAgents | grep homebrew</summary>
<pre>-rw-r--r--   1 ahoi  staff   550 27 Nov 13:54 homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al /Library/LaunchAgents | grep homebrew</summary>
<pre></pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep homebrew</summary>
<pre>-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   602 27 Nov 19:30 homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   500 27 Nov 19:30 homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   586 27 Nov 19:30 homebrew.mxcl.php.plist</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep "com.laravel.valet."</summary>
<pre></pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ls -aln /etc/resolv.conf</summary>
<pre>lrwxr-xr-x  1 0  0  22 18 Okt 05:30 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../var/run/resolv.conf</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>cat /etc/resolv.conf</summary>
<pre>#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
search fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>ifconfig lo0</summary>
<pre>lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD></pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>sh -c 'echo "------\n/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf\n---\n"; cat /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf | grep -n "# valet loopback"; echo "\n------\n"'</summary>
<pre>------
/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf
---

3:    #listen VALET_LOOPBACK:80; # valet loopback

------</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>sh -c 'for file in ~/.config/valet/dnsmasq.d/*; do echo "------\n~/.config/valet/dnsmasq.d/$(basename $file)\n---\n"; cat $file; echo "\n------\n"; done'</summary>
<pre>------
~/.config/valet/dnsmasq.d/tld-test.conf
---

address=/.test/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1

------</pre>
</details>
<details>
<summary>sh -c 'for file in ~/.config/valet/nginx/*; do echo "------\n~/.config/valet/nginx/$(basename $file)\n---\n"; cat $file | grep -n "# valet loopback"; echo "\n------\n"; done'</summary>
<pre>------
~/.config/valet/nginx/*
---

cat: /Users/ahoi/.config/valet/nginx/*: No such file or directory

------</pre>
</details>
```

### Update

Well - I might be on a track:

I found out that the file `File: /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` changes to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string>
                <string>-g</string>
                <string>&#39;daemon off;&#39;</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/opt/homebrew</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

on every service restart. Even if I use the correct one like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string>
                <string>-g</string>
                <string>daemon off;</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/opt/homebrew</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and restart the service - it is being changed after that restart to the faulty version.

As you can see, the `&#39;daemon off;&#39;` part can not work at all.